# Spring data mongodb: mongodb repositories not found when autowired

Tags: spring-mvc, mongodb-java, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following stack:

- Spring MVC web app
- Spring Data MongoDB

When I deploy the webapp and start server (Tomcat 7) I'am getting the following error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.qopuir.repository.UserRepository com.qopuir.service.UserService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.qopuir.repository.UserRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:633)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I don't understand why Repositories are not found during autowiring of Services. Any idea?

This is **web.xml** definition :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Spring Data MongoDB Tutorial</display-name>

    <!--
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    -->

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**applicationContext.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="deployProperties" />

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.qopuir" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <import resource="trace-context.xml" />
    <import resource="spring-data.xml" />


    <bean id="deployProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean" p:location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties" />
</beans>
```

**spring-servlet.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- Declare a view resolver -->
    <bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
        p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" p:order="1" />
</beans>
```

**spring-data.xm** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="deployProperties" />

    <!-- MongoDB host -->
    <mongo:mongo host="${mongo.host.name}" port="${mongo.host.port}" />

    <!-- Template for performing MongoDB operations -->
    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate" c:mongo-ref="mongo" c:databaseName="${mongo.db.name}" />

    <!-- Activate Spring Data MongoDB repository support -->
    <mongo:repositories base-package="com.qoupir.repository" mongo-template-ref="mongoTemplate" />

    <!-- Use this post processor to translate any MongoExceptions thrown in @Repository annotated classes -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

    <!-- Service for initializing MongoDB with sample data using MongoTemplate -->
    <bean id="initMongoService" class="com.qopuir.service.InitMongoService" init-method="init" />
</beans>
```

**trace-context.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- For parsing classes with @Aspect annotation -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean id="customizableTraceInterceptor" class="com.qopuir.aop.TraceInterceptor"
        p:enterMessage="Entering $[targetClassShortName].$[methodName]($[arguments])"
        p:exitMessage="Leaving $[targetClassShortName].$[methodName](): $[returnValue]" />

    <aop:config>
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="customizableTraceInterceptor" pointcut="execution(public * com.qopuir.service..*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="customizableTraceInterceptor" pointcut="execution(public * com.qopuir.controller..*(..))" />
    </aop:config>
</beans>
```

This is one of the repositories :

```
package com.qopuir.repository;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

import com.qopuir.domain.User;

public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Here is the UserService :

```
package com.qopuir.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.qopuir.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.qopuir.repository.UserRepository;

@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    //... some methods
}
```

I don't know if it is a problem of configuration or a problem with version of libraries (I am using the last ones)

**pom.xml** :

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <spring.core.version>3.2.10.RELEASE</spring.core.version>

    <!-- AOP -->        
    <aspectj.version>1.7.4</aspectj.version>

    <!-- Javax Servlet -->
    <tomcat.version>7.0.52</tomcat.version>

    <!-- MongoDB -->
    <mongodb.driver.version>2.12.1</mongodb.driver.version>
    <spring.data.mongodb.version>1.5.2.RELEASE</spring.data.mongodb.version>

    <!-- Logging -->        
    <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>

    <!-- CGLIB -->
    <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AOP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- CGLIB -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>${cglib.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Javax Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MongoDB -->
    <!-- MongoDB Java Driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${mongodb.driver.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Data MongoDB -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.data.mongodb.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the base-package attribute of mongo:repositories in your spring-data.xml file:

```
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.qoupir.repository" mongo-template-ref="mongoTemplate" />
```

should be

```
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.qopuir.repository" mongo-template-ref="mongoTemplate" />
```

Comment: Thank you! What a stupid typo!! It was too late and I was getting crazy, trying things without any sense because of desperation. After having slept a little things are seen from another perspective. I feel a little bit ashamed